# Solr Error 400 unkown field

Tags: solr

Is there a way to skip the Solr 400 unknown field error?

I mean is it possible to simply ignore all the fields passed to the update handler that are not defined in the schema.xml file?

ie.
If my schema.xml is something like:

```
<field name="id"                  type="text_general"  indexed="true"   stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true"/>
<field name="locale"             type="text_general"  indexed="true"   stored="true"/>
<field name="description"         type="text_general"  indexed="true"   stored="true"/>
```

and during the add of a new document I receive a document with the following fields:

```
[id:myID, locale:myLocale, description:myDescription, newField:newField ]
```

how can I avoid the 400 error due to the presence of the "newField".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the `newField` did not explicitly define in your schema.
if  you want to dynamic add some fields,you have to use  [Dynamic Fields](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Dynamic+Fields)